# Authorization error running db2 command line with db2inst1

Tags: db2, docker

I need to enable the COLUMNAR setting in DB2 Express Edition on Docker. For that to work I need to set INTRA_PARALLEL ON at the instance or database level.

I connect to the `db2` command with `db2inst1` that is the instance owner, but I'm getting an error saying that the user is root. How to fix this problem?

```
db2 => connect to bank0002 user db2inst1 using xxxxx

   Database Connection Information

 Database server        = DB2/LINUXX8664 11.5.4.0
 SQL authorization ID   = DB2INST1
 Local database alias   = BANK0002

db2 => UPDATE DBM CFG  USING INTRA_PARALLEL ON
SQL5001N  "ROOT" does not have the authority to change the database manager 
configuration file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update dbm cfg is run by your user in the sh, not the user you connected as. You can attach to the instance as a particular user:

```
db2 attach to instance db2inst1 user db2inst1
```

or:

```
db2 attach to instance db2inst1 user db2inst1 using <password>
```

and then:

```
db2 update dbm cfg using INTRA_PARALLEL YES
```

Documentation can be founds at [ATTACH](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002010.html)

In addition to that, I find it much easier to run db2 directly from the sh (as I did above) instead of starting db2 clp separately. You can use the sh as a host language and for example do loops over a resultset:

```
#> db2 connect to mydb
#> for t in $(db2 -x "select ..."); do
       echo "The table is ${t}"
   done
```

Of course just a silly example, but it is a powerful mechanism for running db2 from a sh script

Comment: Thanks, how do I change the sheapthres configuration parameter as explained [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0000259.html)? I tried unsuccessfully `db2 UPDATE DATABASE MANAGER CONFIGURATION sheapthres 0`

Comment: You do that exactly the same, do you encounter a problem with that?

Comment: I'm getting: `SQL0104N  An unexpected token "sheapthres" was found following 
"CONFIGURATION".  Expected tokens may include:  "MEMBER".  SQLSTATE=42601`

Comment: Oh, try `CFG` istead of `CONFIGURATION`, or the shorter version `db2 update dbm cfg using ...`. You can also stack several changes after each other

Comment: Same problem. I'm getting an error when trying to run a SELECT statement on a columnar table: `[57011]: Sort memory cannot be allocated to process the statement. Reason code = "3".. SQLCODE=-955, SQLSTATE=57011, ` that configuration seems to be the problem

Comment: You may be interested in this article by Mattias Nicola: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1309db2bluaccel/index.html , it is for 10.5 but I believe it is still valid for 11.5. You can use db2set DB2_WORKLOAD=ANALYTICS to change a bunch of settings, and then restart the instance.

Comment: How much shared memory can Db2 use in you container?

Comment: It is BTW a completely different problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117949/discussion-between-lennart-and-ps0604).